# OTS parsing error: OS/2: Version 3 incompatible with selection 256

Tags: fonts, less, magento2

I get an OST parsing error when loading my fonts on chrome: `OTS parsing error: OS/2: Version 3 incompatible with selection 256`, I can't seem to find anyone who has experienced the same error apart from one stackoverflow question that got no reactions.

I load my fonts like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  src: url('../fonts/segoeui.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Using absolute paths like some similar questions suggest doesn't work.
I am extending a theme using a `_extend.less` file in Magento 2.

Comment: I also came across this error.What i noticed was this font works on Microsoft browsers [ IE ] since its a font owned by Microsoft.This font doesn't seem to appear in chrome.